# Kinect Fusion - data format - object segmentation

Tags: kinect, image-segmentation, kinect-sdk, 3d-reconstruction

I have started working with Kinect Fusion recently for my 3D reconstruction project. I have two questions in this field:

1. What is inside .STL file? is it the vertices for different objects in the scene?
2. How can I segment a specific object (e.g. my hand) in the reconstructed file? Is there a way to do so using Kinect Fusion ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there is a Wikipedia article on the STL format:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_format
2. Firstly, you would want your hand to be fixed, because Kinect Fusion will only reconstruct static scenes. Secondly, you could use the min and max depth threshold values to filter out the rest of the scene. Or if that does not work too well, you could reconstruct the whole scene, get the mesh, and then filter out the vertices that are beyond a certain depth for example.